# Difference between "insegnante" and "maestro"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between *insegnante* and *maestro*? From what I know, they both mean “teacher”, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both *maestro and insegnante* are used to refer to a teacher of primary schools in Italy. Insegnante is the more general term to indicate a teacher also at other levels of education.

[Maestro](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/maestro/):

> - Con il nome di maestro sono designati comunemente gli insegnanti di scuola primaria e quelli di scuola dell’infanzia. (With the name of maesto are commonly designated the primary school  teachers and those of kindergarten.)

[Insegnante](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/insegnante/):

> - Chi si dedica all’insegnamento, chi esercita la professione d’insegnare.
>     (Those dedicated to teaching, those who exercise the profession of teaching).
>
>   - insegnante . elementare o di scuola elementare, maestro o maestra; insegnante medio o di scuola media, professore o professoressa (nell’uno e nell’altro caso, si adopera anche, quando non ci sia possibilità di equivoco, **il solo sost. insegnante, che indica tuttavia, più spesso, il maestro elementare**)
>   - (teacher. elementary or primary school teacher or teacher; middle or secondary school teacher, professor or teacher (in either case, is also working, when there is no possibility of misunderstanding, **the only noun. teacher, indicates, however, more often, the primary school teacher**);.

Please note that maestro is also used to indicate a *master, a leader or a very skilled artisan*.

Comment: +1. Still, Josh, please rewrite the whole answer (including the citations) in English. The question was in English and the OP might not understand  Italian citations without translation.

Comment: Outside school, I think *maestro* is more common: *maestro di scherma*, *maestro di tennis* (fencing/tennis teacher).

Comment: @Federico - wouldn'd *istruttore* be a more common term in that context?

Comment: @Josh61 Personally I find both *maestro* and *istruttore* correct, and I would use them interchangeably (perhaps favoring *maestro* in an informal register). Maybe *maestro* has a slight hint of a more personal teacher-student relationship.

Comment: I'd add to this answer another possible use: 'Maestro' is also used to indicate a **graduated and skilled musician or orchestra director**. Professional pianists are, for instance, addressed as 'Maestro' regardless of their gender. That is one case where 'insegnante' cannot be used.

Comment: Consider _docente_ and _professore_ too

Answer (score 4):

As well as the slight semantic difference already outlined, when talking to their teacher children wouldn't call him `insegnante`, they'd call him `maestro`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is active once more, I thought I would give my contribution as well.

Besides the other excellent answers, note that the word *maestro* can seldom be used in a doctorate setting when somebody who has already achieved the *dottorato* speaks about their supervisor in a respectful way.

> Il professor Rossi, il mio maestro, era un acuto osservatore.

As Federico Poloni suggested in a comment, the teacher-student relationship is strongly hinted at in this context. Using *maestro* in this context does suggest the reverence that the speaker has towards his mentor.